# Entity Framework if statement inside select

Tags: sql, asp.net, entity-framework

I have a problem in generating an Entity Framework query and not okay with linq style one :.....

This is my attempt:

```
var query = db.table
              .Where(x => x.colA == 1)
              .GroupBy(x => new {x.min,x.max})
              .Select(y => if(y.key.min==0 && y.key.max==0)
                              { " unchanged " } 
                           else 
                              { y.key.min.tostring()+" "+y.key.max.tostring() })
              .ToList()
```

I want to get "unchanged" string, if both value ofmin and max are zero, otherwise concat them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently all elements in your table have properties `min` and `max`

After `GroupBy(x=> new {x.min,x.max})` you'll have a sequence of groups, where each group has a key {min, max}, all elements in the group have this value for their min and max properties.

After the `GroupBy`, you take every group, and from every group you'll select exactly one string. You get rid of the element of the group.

The string that you select depends on the key of the group: if the key = {0, 0} you select the string "unchanged", else you select the string:

```
y.key.min.tostring()+" "+y.key.max.tostring()
```

The result is a list of strings, something like:

```
 "3 7",
 "4 10,
 "unchanged",
 "2 8",
```

Are you sure you want this?

In that case you won't need the GroupBy. Distinct will be simpler and faster

```
List<string> result = db.table
   .Where(tableRow => tableRow.colA == 1)
   .Select(tableRow => tableRow.min==0 && tableRow.max==0 
         ? " unchanged " 
         : tableRow.min.tostring()+" "+tableRow.max.tostring())
   // from here you have a sequence of strings
   // get rid of duplicates:
   .Distinct()
   .ToList();
```

Comment: thank you for full description @harald coppoolse... most answer in this section is correct ... i mark this answer due to full describing and understanding

Answer (score 4):

Use the [conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator)

```
// ...

.Select(y=> y.key.min==0 && y.key.max==0 
             ? " unchanged " 
             : y.key.min.tostring()+" "+y.key.max.tostring())
// ...
```

Answer (score 1):

For this specific case, you can use Conditional Operator (`?:`)

```
var query = db.table
            .Where(x=> x.colA == 1)
            .GroupBy(x=> new {x.min,x.max})
            .Select(y=> (y.Key.min == 0 && y.Key.max == 0) ? " unchanged" : (y.Key.min.ToString()+" "+y.Key.max.ToString()))
            .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I can't try it right now, but i think this should work

```
var query = db.table
   .Where(x=> x.colA == 1)
   .GroupBy(x=> new {x.min,x.max})
   .Select(y=>  {if(y.key.min==0 && y.key.max==0)
                { 
                    " unchanged " 
                } else 
                { 
                    y.key.min.tostring()+" "+y.key.max.tostring(); 
                } return y;})
    .ToList()
```